# Getting a local image in PDF using DOMPDF

Tags: php, dompdf

I am new to PHP and trying to build a little project for my assignment.

I am trying to convert some HTML to a PDF using PHP (DOMPDF package). The HTML does contain some  tags to output some images that are locally stored within the this project's folder.

I am currently getting "Image not found or type unknown" error, which I have seen is quite common when trying to do this.

I have done some research and experimented with quite a few different things, however I do not seem to be getting anywhere unfortunately.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Just a little snippet from my project:

index.php

```
<?php 

require_once 'packages/dompdf/autoload.inc.php'; 

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$dompdf->loadHtml("<img src='photo.jpeg'>");

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait'); 
 
$dompdf->render(); 

$dompdf->stream("test-pdf", array("Attachment" => 0));

?>
```

The image is stored in the same directory as the index.php file. I am using XAMPP as a development environment.

Hope this is described correctly. Thanks everyone and appreciate the support!

Comment: You would need to start by including the full path to the image, including the `https://` bit. That's because inside DomPDF it is unclear where the HTML is located on the web. But that's not all, I think. I always take the easy way out with DomPDF and just include the image as base64 code. This link might be useful for that: https://www.base64-image.de/

Comment: Thank you @KIKOSoftware I will give this a go! Was thinking it was something to do with the file path that cannot be found. Will let you guys know how I get on with this. Much appreciated.

Comment: Amazing thank you for your help with this it does seem to work now. However I do need to have GD extension enabled, which I think when it get submitted to my lecturer they will not have this extension enabled, is it possible without this extension?

Comment: You can read about the DOMPDF requirements here: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Requirements Most installations of PHP will include the GD extension, and you need to process the image somehow. DOMPDF cannot work without, as will most other PDF packages. If you read it carefully you could try a JPEG image, and see if it will work without the GD extension... I have my doubts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @KIKOSoftware mentioned in the comments, the `src` attribute of an `img` tag can either contain an [**absolute** URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#page-27) or base64-encoded image data. You can use the following helper function to generate the latter on the fly.

```
function ImageToDataUrl(String $filename) : String {
    if(!file_exists($filename))
        throw new Exception('File not found.');
    
    $mime = mime_content_type($filename);
    if($mime === false) 
        throw new Exception('Illegal MIME type.');

    $raw_data = file_get_contents($filename);
    if(empty($raw_data))
        throw new Exception('File not readable or empty.');
    
    return "data:{$mime};base64," . base64_encode($raw_data);
}
```

Which will then be used like this:

```
$dompdf->loadHtml("<img src='" . ImageToDataUrl('photo.jpeg') . "'>");
```

Comment: Thanks for the input and clarity on how to exactly accomplish this, will give it a go tomorrow and keep you guys informed on my progress. Thank you!

Comment: Amazing thank you for your help with this it does seem to work now. However I do need to have GD extension enabled, which I think when it get submitted to my lecturer they will not have this extension enabled, is it possible without this extension?

Comment: My function does not need GD to be enabled, but I think it's a dependency for DOMPDF.

Comment: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Requirements#optional-dependencies

Comment: Thank you for your help have got it working now. I was trying it with a PNG which according to the dompdf documentation you sent required GD as support. However JPEG files are fine and do not require GD and will run using default DOMPDF package. Thanks again for your help really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad it works! Please don't forget to accept the answer (and upvote if you can).